# Promedio de edad en una clase

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

tengo un problema que no me aprueba los test y no entiendo porque

```
getPromedioEdad() {
      // Escribe una función que retorne el promedio de edad de los amigos de una persona
      // ej, si la persona tuviera estos amigos:
      // {
      //   amigos: [{
      //     nombre: 'toni',
      //     edad: 33,
      //   }, {
      //     nombre: 'Emi',
      //     edad: 25
      //   }]
      // }
      // persona.getPromedioEdad() // retorna 29
}
```

Intente resolverlo de esta manera pero me retorna 0 en las pruebas

```
var edad = 0
       for(let i =0; i<this.amigos.edad; i++) {
         edad = edad + this.amigos.edad[i]
       }
       var cantidad = this.amigos.length-1
       var total = edad/cantidad;
       return total
```

Esto es lo que me sale en el test
Clase › crearClasePersona › should get age average with getPromedioEdad

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: 29
Received: 0

  118 |           edad: 25
  119 |         }]);
> 120 |       expect(persona.getPromedioEdad()).toBe(29);
      |                                         ^
  121 |     });
  122 |   });
  123 | });
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Has revisado qué hay en `this.amigos.edad[i]` para cada iteración? No te has preguntado si, tal vez, estás iterando sobre el elemento incorrecto? Yo iteraría sobre amigos y buscaría el atributo edad de cada uno... en tu caso, puedes usar (temporalmente) `console.log` e ir pintanto lo que intentas sumar. :)

Answer (score 2):

tengo la impresion de que estas iterando de manera incorrecta, especificamente en esta linea
`for(let i =0; i<this.amigos.edad; i++) {`

El this.amigos.edad deberia darte undefined ya que no es un objeto.

Te propongo usar esta opcion:

```js
const  amigos = [{
           nombre: 'toni',
           edad: 33,
         }, {
           nombre: 'Emi',
           edad: 25
         }];
         
const result = amigos.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.edad, 0) / amigos.length;

console.log(result);
```

Tambien te dejo el link de uso del reduce que suele ser un poco complicado de utilizar:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce

Comment: Gracias me funciono, el test lo corri sin declarar el objeto amigos pero poniendo en el reduce this.amigos y paso !!!

Comment: @Snowi jejeje, pero sí entendiste qué está pasando en el código? Como sea, recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta si resolvió tu problema :)